# How to convert apks file to apk file on mobile phone?

Tags: apk

I downloaded an apks file, and I want to convert it into an apk file for installation. Is there any app or method to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several converters on the internet that can help you with that. Once I used "AntiSplit G2" app on an Android device to convert XAPK to APK, but it works with APKs too. Give it a try!

As I remember, you can't find AntiSplit G2 on Google Play, so you'll have to search other platforms to download the app. Make sure you don't download something from a sus website.